# Graphing Level Curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm not too sure how to go about doing questions like these. This is from the text and I wanted to know the steps I take when doing level curve questions like the ones attached. Specifically question 31.

[image: LEVEL CURVE QUESTION]

Comment: Transform it into $y^2=x-z \iff y=\pm \sqrt{x-z}$ (where $z$ is a parameter) ; changing the value of $z$ will give you a family of parabolas  $y=\pm \sqrt{x}, y=\pm \sqrt{x-1}, \  y=\pm \sqrt{x-2}$, etc. with common axis $Ox$, that are the level curves of the given surface.

Comment: What is the relevance of the two vectors being multiplied? (What am I supposed to do with the coordinates?)

Comment: $[0,4] \times [-2,2]$ isn't the (ordinary) product of two vectors : it is the cartesian products of two sets describing the rectangle in which we consider the surface. $(x,y) \in [0,4] \times [-2,2] \iff (0 \leq x \leq 4) \ \text{and} \ (-2 \leq y \leq 2)$

Comment: How does that information now assist with the graphing of the function?

Comment: See the text I have added to my previous answer.

Comment: Sorry I am still not understanding

Comment: For instance why is it a parabola?

Comment: If you exchange the rôles of $x$ and $y$ in equation $x=y^2+z$ (an operation which amounts do operate a symmetry with respect to straight line with equation $y=x$), you get $y=x^2+z$ a second degree curve which is known to be a parabola.